# photo and video sharing on facebook in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have to share the photo on facebook for which i have written the following code

```
 try
        {

            labelSteps_1_2.Text = "<a name=\"fb_share\" type=\"button\"></a>" +
                "<script " +
                "src=\"http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share\" " +
                "type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";

            HtmlMeta tag = new HtmlMeta();
            tag.Name = "title";
            tag.Content = "This is the Title";
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag);




            HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
            link.Href = "http://admin.bizofair.com/UploadOffers/O_O11090004_14032012053503_183_183.jpeg";
            link.Attributes["rel"] = "image_src";
            link.Style.Add("color", "red");
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle the exception
        }
```

on page load but it is not showing the image and when i have paste url of my image in facebook debugger on facebook developer it is giving error 
    Errors That Must Be Fixed

Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.